# Determinant of Multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I´m trying to compute the determinant of a numpy array M, with np.shape(M) = (N, L, L) is something like:

```
import numpy as np

M = np.random.rand(1000*10*10).reshape(1000, 10, 10)
dm = np.zeros(1000)
for _ in xrange(len(dm)):
    dm[_] = np.linalg.det(M[_])
```

Is there a way without looping? "N" is some orders of magnitude larger than "L". I thought of something like:

```
np.apply_over_axes(np.linalg.det(M), axis=0)
```

Is there a faster way doing what I want? I guess the loop overhead is a performance bottleneck because the determinant of small matrices is a relatively cheap operation (or am I wrong?).

Answer (score 7):

You need to modify `np.linalg.det` to get the speed. The idea is that `det()` is a Python function, it does a lot of check first, and call the fortran routine, and does some array calculate to get the result.

Here is the code from numpy:

```
def slogdet(a):
    a = asarray(a)
    _assertRank2(a)
    _assertSquareness(a)
    t, result_t = _commonType(a)
    a = _fastCopyAndTranspose(t, a)
    a = _to_native_byte_order(a)
    n = a.shape[0]
    if isComplexType(t):
        lapack_routine = lapack_lite.zgetrf
    else:
        lapack_routine = lapack_lite.dgetrf
    pivots = zeros((n,), fortran_int)
    results = lapack_routine(n, n, a, n, pivots, 0)
    info = results['info']
    if (info < 0):
        raise TypeError, "Illegal input to Fortran routine"
    elif (info > 0):
        return (t(0.0), _realType(t)(-Inf))
    sign = 1. - 2. * (add.reduce(pivots != arange(1, n + 1)) % 2)
    d = diagonal(a)
    absd = absolute(d)
    sign *= multiply.reduce(d / absd)
    log(absd, absd)
    logdet = add.reduce(absd, axis=-1)
    return sign, logdet

def det(a):
    sign, logdet = slogdet(a)
    return sign * exp(logdet)
```

To speedup this function, you can omit the check (it becomes your Responsibility to keep the input right), and collect the fortran results in an array, and do the final calculations for all the small arrays without for loop.

Here is my result:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core import intc
from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite

N = 1000
M = np.random.rand(N*10*10).reshape(N, 10, 10)

def dets(a):
    length = a.shape[0]
    dm = np.zeros(length)
    for i in xrange(length):
        dm[i] = np.linalg.det(M[i])
    return dm

def dets_fast(a):
    m = a.shape[0]
    n = a.shape[1]
    lapack_routine = lapack_lite.dgetrf
    pivots = np.zeros((m, n), intc)
    flags = np.arange(1, n + 1).reshape(1, -1)
    for i in xrange(m):
        tmp = a[i]
        lapack_routine(n, n, tmp, n, pivots[i], 0)
    sign = 1. - 2. * (np.add.reduce(pivots != flags, axis=1) % 2)
    idx = np.arange(n)
    d = a[:, idx, idx]
    absd = np.absolute(d)
    sign *= np.multiply.reduce(d / absd, axis=1)
    np.log(absd, absd)
    logdet = np.add.reduce(absd, axis=-1)
    return sign * np.exp(logdet)

print np.allclose(dets(M), dets_fast(M.copy()))
```

and the speed is:

```
timeit dets(M)
10 loops, best of 3: 159 ms per loop

timeit dets_fast(M)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
```

So, by doing this, you can speedup by 15 times. That is a good result without any compiled code.

**note: I omit the error check for the fortran routine.**

Comment: Thank you very much for your example code and that you even did the timing. It works very well for small quadratic matrices (O(MxM)) and doesn´t get worse than the implemented numpy.linalg.det for N ~ M.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get apply_over_axes to work, because this is a 3D array I think. Anyway, profiling the code shows that the program spends little time in the loop,

```
import cProfile
import pstats
N=10000
M = np.random.rand(N*10*10).reshape(N, 10, 10)
def f(M):
    dm = np.zeros(N)
    for _ in xrange(len(dm)):
        dm[_] = np.linalg.det(M[_])
    return dm
cProfile.run('f(M)','foo')
p = pstats.Stats('foo')
res = p.sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats(10)
```

The result is "0.955 seconds" of runtime, with 0.930s of cumulative time spent in linalg.py:1642(det).

If I perform the same test with 2x2 matrices, I get .844s of total time, and .821s in linalg.py:1642(det), despite the matrices being small. Then, it seems that the `det()` function that has a large overhead for small matrices.

Doing it with 30x30, I get a total time 1.198s, and a time in `det()` of 1.172.

With 70x70, total is 3.122, and time in `det()` is 3.094, with less than 1% in the loop.

It seems that in any case, it is not worth optimizing the python loop.